# Android Webview with HTML 5 geolocation

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I am using a webview to load a web application. Within the page I load I use the HTML 5 geolocation API to detect the users location. This works in all browsers and currently have it working from an iOS application. For some reason I can't get it to work from within an Android webview. When I run the code below I am seeing this message in the stack trace:

[INFO:CONSOLE(24)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: PageMethods is not defined", source: [THE URL FOR THE SCRIPT] (24)

Again this functions just fine in a browser.

```
    package bar.krowd.krowdapp;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView KrowdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        KrowdView = (WebView) findViewById((R.id.activity_main_webview));

        WebSettings ws = KrowdView.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setGeolocationEnabled(true);


        KrowdView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        KrowdView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());

        KrowdView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        KrowdView.loadUrl([I AM PUTTING THE URL HERE]);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Pop the browser back stack or exit the activity
    if (KrowdView.canGoBack()) {
        KrowdView.goBack();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                   GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
        // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
        // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}

}
```

I have the following listed in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bug, i solved it downgrading targetSdkVersion from 23 to 21 in app build.gradle

Comment: this should be in the comments section not answers

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I looks like it isn't finding jQuery. I know jQuery is functioning though as an animation before the location loads is still functioning. As you can see from below, I am getting an "application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions" error.

Comment: I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(117)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined", source: [Script URL] (117)
11-23 20:33:33.689 2168-2168/bar.krowd.krowdapp E/LocationProvider: Caught security exception while registering for location updates from the system. The application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions.
11-23 20:33:34.006 2168-2168/bar.krowd.krowdapp I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined", source: [Script URL] (2)